# How to manually autoscale pods while load balancing?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, scaling

I have tried defining `LoadBalancer` in my service type and creating a deployment for it with 3 replicas:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: springboot-postgres-k8s
  labels:
    name: springboot-postgres-k8s
spec:
  ports: # ...
  selector: # type: ...
  type: LoadBalancer # <=====

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-postgres-k8s
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-postgres-k8s
  replicas: 3 # <=====
  template: # ...
```

This starts up three pod and a load balancer which successfully load balances request among these three pods.

I want to know if k8s allows to manually autoscale the pods. That is if my cluster with 3 replicas + a load balancer is up and running, how can I manually increase replicas and still make the existing load balancer to scale across all 4 replicas (3 old and one newly created)?

Do I have to run ([ref1](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubectl-scale#2) [ref2](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_scale/)):

```
kubectl scale --current-replicas=3 --replicas=4 deployment/springboot-postgres-k8s
```

**Q1.** Will above command notify existing load balancer of newly created pod?

or I have to run following (as specified in ref2)

```
kubectl scale --replicas=4 -f foo.yaml
```

**Q2.** Will above command notify existing load balancer of newly created pod?
**Q3.** What if my foo.yaml contains both service and deployment definition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its allows manual autoscale.

When you create a service in Kubernetes, k8s automatically creates **kind: Endpoints** type resource(s) for your pods with a matching label selector. This resource referenced by a Service to define which Pods the traffic can be sent to and periodically updated by the k8s when pods are created or deleted.

So regardless of the creation time of resources, k8s will handle the update and pods will be able to receive traffic from loadbalancer.

Comment: Small follow up question: how can I know whether loadbalancer has started delegating traffic to newly created pod? That is, is there any log maintained by k8s or some command output which tells number of pods against which loadbalancer is balancing the load?

Comment: When pods status become Ready, traffic will be sent to it but I dont know if there is command/log to see it.

Comment: I confirm that load balancer does indeed considers newly created pod for balancing load. This might be obvious to those who know the internal working / design of k8s. But I just want to explicitly check. I created REST end point which returns pod-specific randomly generated UUID. When one pod was running, REST endpoint always returned same UUID. When pods replicas are increased, REST endpoints started returning multiple UUIDs across multiple requests to those endpoints.

Comment: Also you might want to take look at this.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#proxy-mode-iptables